# Anchors [akLeft, akRight, akBottom] not working properly

Tags: delphi, alignment, anchor

I have a small problem with anchors.

I have a form with 2 panels, `Panel1` is aligned to left and `Panel2` is on the first, not aligned but anchored top and bottom. On the second panel there are two edits, they are anchored left, right and bottom only. This design causes a "minimizing" sliding effect whereby the edits disappear at the top when the form is resized. This is intended.

On the start of the application, the initial state of the second panel should be invisible, thus I use `Panel2.Height := 0`.

But after resizing the form, or manually setting `Panel2.Height := 104`, the edits are not dragged down to their anchored positions, but they remain invisible beyond the panel.

This is the sample code which could help to visualize it:

```
// unit 1
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMoveEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; X, Y: Integer) of object;

  TLabeledEdit = class(ExtCtrls.TLabeledEdit)
  private
    FOnMove: TMoveEvent;
    procedure WMMove(var Message: TWMMove); message WM_MOVE;
  public
    property OnMove: TMoveEvent read FOnMove write FOnMove;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    LabeledEdit1: TLabeledEdit;
    LabeledEdit2: TLabeledEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure LE1Move(Sender: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LE2Move(Sender: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  TypInfo;

const
  MaxSet = 255; // Largest ordinal value in a Delphi set.

type
  TSet = set of 0..MaxSet;

function SetToString(Info: PTypeInfo; const Value; const Separator, Prefix, Suffix: string): String; overload;
var
  CompInfo: PTypeInfo;
  CompData: PTypeData;
  SetValue: TSet absolute Value;
  Element: 0..MaxSet;
begin
  CompInfo:=GetTypeData(Info)^.CompType^;
  CompData:=GetTypeData(CompInfo);
  Result:='';
  for Element:=CompData.MinValue to CompData.MaxValue do begin
    if Element in SetValue then
      if Result = '' then
        Result := Prefix + GetEnumName(CompInfo, Element)
      else
        Result := Result + Separator + GetEnumName(CompInfo, Element);
  end;
  if Result = '' then
    Result := Prefix + Suffix
  else
    Result := Result + Suffix;
end;

function SetToString(Info: PTypeInfo; const Value; const Separator: string): String; overload;
begin
  Result:=SetToString(Info, Value, Separator, '[', ']');
end;

function SetToString(Info: PTypeInfo; const Value): String; overload;
begin
  Result:=SetToString(Info, Value, ', ');
end;

{ TLabeledEdit }

procedure TLabeledEdit.WMMove(var Message: TWMMove);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnMove) then
    FOnMove(Self, Message.XPos, Message.YPos);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LabeledEdit1.OnMove:=LE1Move;
  LabeledEdit2.OnMove:=LE2Move;
end;

procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  Panel2.Height:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel2.Height:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel2.Height:=104;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('LE1 Anchors = ' + SetToString(TypeInfo(TAnchors), LabeledEdit1.Anchors));
  ShowMessage('LE2 Anchors = ' + SetToString(TypeInfo(TAnchors), LabeledEdit2.Anchors));
end;

procedure TForm1.LE1Move(Sender: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Label1.Caption:=Format('LE1 pos: %d : %d', [X, Y]);
end;

procedure TForm1.LE2Move(Sender: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Label2.Caption:=Format('LE2 pos: %d : %d', [X, Y]);
end;

end.

// dfm
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 304
  ClientWidth = 643
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 200
    Top = 56
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 200
    Top = 96
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label2'
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 185
    Height = 304
    Align = alLeft
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 152
    ExplicitTop = 96
    ExplicitHeight = 41
    DesignSize = (
      185
      304)
    object Panel2: TPanel
      Left = 1
      Top = 81
      Width = 183
      Height = 104
      Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
      Constraints.MaxHeight = 104
      TabOrder = 0
      DesignSize = (
        183
        104)
      object LabeledEdit1: TLabeledEdit
        Left = 8
        Top = 24
        Width = 121
        Height = 21
        Anchors = [akLeft, akRight, akBottom]
        EditLabel.Width = 61
        EditLabel.Height = 13
        EditLabel.Caption = 'LabeledEdit1'
        TabOrder = 0
      end
      object LabeledEdit2: TLabeledEdit
        Left = 48
        Top = 72
        Width = 121
        Height = 21
        Anchors = [akLeft, akRight, akBottom]
        EditLabel.Width = 61
        EditLabel.Height = 13
        EditLabel.Caption = 'LabeledEdit2'
        TabOrder = 1
      end
    end
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 200
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Hide'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 281
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Show'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Left = 200
    Top = 140
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Anchors'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = Button3Click
  end
end
```

If `Panel2.Height` is not set to 0 after form create, the edits moves up and down when form is resized. If `Panel2.Height` is set to 0 on form create, the edits stay invisible out of the `Panel2`, and if `Panel2` is shown, they stay invisible whereby the `Top` positions are negative.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Don't set the panel `Height` to 0, let the height be what it is and change the `Visible` property to `False` when you don't want the panel to be visible.

Comment: This action results in the loss of functionality in question.

Comment: Please add your [previous edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15093331/2) as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Set `Panel2`'s height to zero in the form's `OnShow` event instead of in `AfterConstruction`, or
2. Place another panel on `Panel2` with `Align=alBottom`.

Exactly why the first solution *does* work I don't know, but it certainly has merit, because during `OnCreate` (or `AfterConstruction` as you use), the windowed control handles aren't allocated yet.

Comment: It really works, the first solution. You are brilliant, thanks for that. As you can see, I have no idea why this solution works, and why by using my solution does not. Why on `OnCreate` or `AfterConstruction` after setting `Panel2.Height:=0` edits are moved up (off the client area of the `Panel2`), it is strange why then they won't move back down.

Answer (score 3):

Anchored controls prefer to have their anchored positions at locations that actually exist. Delphi has trouble arranging controls in spaces where they don't all fit. Anchors can get "stuck" at the wrong locations, and adjacent aligned controls can accidentally trade places with each other.

When the panel that the controls live on changes to have positive size, adjust the controls' locations so that they're where you want them to be. As long as they remain visible (i.e., as long as the panel isn't collapsed to zero height), their anchors will continue to keep them in the right spots.

Comment: Is there any workaround to situation when control is moved to position at which it is not visible, but still have valid anchors. You wrote that Delphi has trouble with this behavior, so I assume that this is known bug and there is a solution to it, is there any?

Comment: I don't really consider it a bug. It's more of a corner case where the expected behavior isn't well defined, and it's hard to implement. Why are you moving controls to places where they're not visible? Stop doing that, and the anchoring problem goes away.

Comment: Why? I'm using this to make some nice trick, smooth resizing form, where some controls hides and shows up if form is re-resized again. I really thought that anchors do the trick. Maybe You know where to look, into VCL source, for any clues describing that anchors "buggy" behavior. Maybe I can do something to repair this, in the form of some sort of run-time fix. It really can't be impossible to do.

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround to this problem, but it is not related with anchors, it has more to do with `Align = alCustom`...

But if anyone is interested with how I solved it, here is some code to explain it.

```
// modified form create procedure
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LabeledEdit1.Align:=alCustom; // go to hell with automation
  LabeledEdit1.Anchors:=[akLeft, akRight, akBottom]; // this can be ommited
  LabeledEdit2.Align:=alCustom; // go to hell with automation
  LabeledEdit2.Anchors:=[akLeft, akRight, akBottom]; // this can be ommited
  LabeledEdit1.OnMove:=LE1Move;
  LabeledEdit2.OnMove:=LE2Move;
end;
```

We need to handle `OnAlignPosition` for `Panel2`.

```
type
  TUnProtectedWinControl = class(TWinControl);

procedure TForm1.Panel2AlignPosition(Sender: TWinControl; Control: TControl; var NewLeft, NewTop, NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var AlignRect: TRect; AlignInfo: TAlignInfo);
begin
  if (Sender <> Nil) and (Sender is TWinControl) then begin
    if Control.Parent <> Nil then begin
      if Control.ExplicitTop > 0 then
        NewTop:=Control.Parent.Height - (TUnProtectedWinControl(Sender).FDesignSize.Y - Control.ExplicitTop)
      else
        NewTop:=Control.Parent.Height + Control.ExplicitTop;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with 11.3 and fix it by disable this setting:

```
Options -> User Interface -> FormDesigner -> Enable VCL Style
```